# java: converting binary to text?

Tags: java, binary

I wrote this code for converting binary to text .

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

      BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      System.out.println("Enter a binary value:");
      String h = b.readLine();
      int k = Integer.parseInt(h,2);  
      String out = new Character((char)k).toString();
      System.out.println("string: " + out);
      } 
}
```

and look at the output !

```
Enter a binary value:
0011000100110000
string: ?
```

what's the problem?

Comment: What do you want the output to be?

Comment: the out put should be string , like 0011010100110101 = 55  or 011000010110000101100001 = aaa

Comment: You want it to get parsed as ASCII....?  Or what?

Comment: I want it to convert to text(ascii)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

instead of

```
String out = new Character((char)k).toString();
```

do

```
String out = String.valueOf(k);
```

### EDIT:

```
String input = "011000010110000101100001";
String output = "";
for(int i = 0; i <= input.length() - 8; i+=8)
{
    int k = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(i, i+8), 2);
    output += (char) k;
}
```

Comment: that's not what I want it converts hexa decimal to string I think

Answer (score 0):

Even Simpler:

```
String out=""+k;
```

Comment: it converts hexa decimal to string ! not binary to string

Comment: you want it to convert to a char first and then to string? please be more clear

Comment: I want to convert to text (ascii)